# Tuning memory weblogic 12c on Linux

Tags: weblogic

I'm using weblogic 12c in a cluster with 8 weblogics running on 4 servers (2 Nodes/1 server)

- RAM: 64GB each server.
- I set RAM on 1 nodes is 26GB, when a node start it using about 10GB, but when running about a week, it increase 26GB nearly.
- The number co-current: 70 sessions/1 Node (Monitor in Home >Summary of Services >Summary of Servers >Summary of Services >Summary of Servers >Summary of Deployments >Test)

I think my nodes eating many of memory and I have to restart servers.

Pls help me tuning server/weblogic.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you might be experiencing memory leak problem. There are a lot of tools out there which could help you find root cause. As a starting point it will be good if you configure your WebLogic to take heap dump when Java Out of Memory condition occurs. This can be done by setting JVM options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath
```

Alternative would be to take heap dump manually via command line before you make your weekly restart.

When you have your heap dump file load it into Eclipse Memory Analyzer and run leak suspects report.